# Sass error when using @import

Tags: css, sass

When I write, in SASS:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic);
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Invalid CSS after "...,800,800italic)": expected media query list, was ";"
```

I don't have any media queries, though. How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried wrapping the URL in quotes? Seems it is trying to parse part of the URL as css.

```
url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic');
```

Comment: Try getting rid of the url function, and adding a .css extension - @import "https://...". It's possible this is the same error - https://github.com/sass/libsass/issues/289

Comment: Yep, once I got rid of the url it seems to work fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your import has to be in quotes! Like this:

@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic");

You can read more about imports at: http://sass-lang.com/guide under "Import".

Hope that helps!

Comment: Interesting. I just did a quick file to test this out importing the fonts you are trying to import and it works for me, so make sure there is no weird typos or missed parenthesis or anything anywhere!